# Connection problems of esp8266

Tags: arduino, esp8266

As soon as I am connecting 3.3 v from Arduino to ch_pd and vcc of esp8266, the port connected to Arduino becomes unavailable. Can you let me know how to proceed. I am using pin 2 of Arduino to tx of esp8266 and pin 3 to rx.

Comment: Which Arduino is it? Are you using software serial port?  What is on pin 0 and 1?

Comment: Arduino Uno R3 ATmega328P ATMEGA16U2 and coming to the connections  3.3 V of arduino is connected to ch_pd and VCC of esp8266 and i am using pin2 and Pin 3 for tx and rx abd connected to esp8266, gnd is connected to gnd

Comment: i am not using pin 0 and pin 1

Comment: i tried pino and pin 1 with bare minimum sketch and its not working. The problem is same as soon as i connect the 3.3v to vcc of ESp8266 the com 7 port becomes unavailable for uploading of code and throwing an error

Comment: Does your esp8266 run by itself?  Without the Arduino?

Comment: how to run esp8266 by itself. Can you tell me the connections an dcode

Comment: here is a way using python: [http://fab.cba.mit.edu/classes/863.14/tutorials/Programming/serialwifi.html](http://fab.cba.mit.edu/classes/863.14/tutorials/Programming/serialwifi.html)

Answer (score 1):

ESP8266 require much current. Maybe regulator of arduino is not capable of powering much current and thatswhy its output voltage drops when you connect ch_pd and vcc.
Try using another power source.

Comment: Dear Himanshu, I even tried connecting a separate Regulated DC source available in the lab but the problem still persists. Is there a way to come out of this.

Comment: but still i will try a voltage regulator

Comment: Are you using software serial? Pin no 0 of Arduino Uno is RX and 1 is TX.

Comment: maybe esp8266 is having problem.You can check using another ESP.

Comment: you need an external power supply for the esp, and also a logical level converter for thr Rx pin (esp is 3.3 v logic, and arduino 5 v logic). Please show wiring and console log for further help.